# Can a class that extends a base class be extended to be based only on an extension?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, subclassing

I realize the title is confusing, but I could not think how to ask it without a book. My question is: I have an abstract class that is extending a library base class. That dependent library class has sub classes also. I then have a series of sub classes from the abstract class. The problem is that one of my sub classes requires that the abstract be based on one of the library sub classes while all of the others only need the original base class.

As an example, assume I have a library with a class PERSON. The library also has several sub classes CHILD, YOUTH, MIDDLE_AGE and ELDERLY, each with their own attributes/methods. In my code, I have an abstract class EMPLOYEE that extends PERSON. It has several sub classes NEW_HIRE, LINE_WORKER, MANAGER, and RETIRING. Most simply use the PERSON class methods, but the RETIRING sub class is only valid is the PERSON type is actually an ELDERLY (it needs certain methods in that class). The library is immutable, so I cannot make changes to it.

Another example would be code that was based on a collection type such as Set, but had a specific sub-class that required the set to be an TreeSet (e.g. it needs the ceiling() functionality).

Is there a way to specify this?

Comment: It looks like what you really need is either interfaces or decorators.

Comment: If you need RETIRING to get ELDERLY method, you can make ELDERLY extend ELDERLY

Comment: This smells of being an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) type question. Those classes should be part of a Person by composition, not by inheritance. Your design is all wrong and you're trying to fix a broken design. Don't. Refactor the whole thing into a more sensible whole.

Comment: For instance, those age specifiers would be an enum, and the Person would have a field of that enum type. Same for the WorkStatus, an enum or separate class, and Person would hold a field of this type.

Comment: I agree the design is an issue, but that was the reason for the question.As I stated, the code is in a supplied library that cannot be changed. It provides a framework with operations across the base type. My requirement is to create an orthogonal secondary frame work whose objects extend from the library base class (so the library framework continues to function on them) while also supporting a secondary one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, it seems that , making reference to your Person example, the Person class is extended in two directions, Age and Work.
Accepted that the Age direction cannot be touched because it is in the library, the inheritance relation involving the Work direction is problematic.
So, if a were you, I would use **composition**.

> The library also has several sub classes CHILD, YOUTH, MIDDLE_AGE and ELDERLY, each with their own attributes/methods.

The sentence opens two scenarios:

1. Employee needs methods that are declared in the Person abstract class
2. Employee needs methods that are declared in Person subclasses

Scenario 1 is the simplest: Employee owns a reference to a Person object and trought it  invokes methods of Person by forwarding.

```
public abstract class Employee{
    private Person person;
    //... 

    Employee(Person p){
       this.person=p;
    }

    public getName(){      // basic example
       person.getName();
    }
```

Scenario 2 (that it seems to me being your case) follows by the previous, but is a bit complex because it requires to be applied to each "Work subclass" that needs methods declared in the "Age subclasses".
Focusing on the Retiring case, this approach requires that the Retiring object owns a reference to Enderly directly.

```
public class Retiring extends Employee{
     private Enderly enderly;

     Retiring( Enderly e){
       this.enderly=e;
     }

     public getBenefits(){
         enderly.getMoney();
     }
```

Comment: Scenario 2 is correct, and the answer supplied is correct for the way I had phrased the question.